# Check if string only contains a certain character in python

Tags: python, string, command-line-arguments

How would I go about checking if a string only contains a certain character?

```py
string_to_check = "aaaaaa"
character = "a"
```

I have tried

```py
elif " " in cmd:
     return print(Fore.RED + f"Input cannot be nothing.")
```

But this applies to strings *with the character in it*, I would like to apply string with *only the character in it*...
For example

```py
does_contain_only("a", "aaaaaa") # True
does_contain_only("a", "aaaaba") # False
```

Although I don't know any commands / functions to do this,

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please share the full code snippet and expected output examples.

Comment: Is it always comparing one *single* character?

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a string only contains a certain character, like this:

```py
def does_contain_only(char, string):
    return all([c == char for c in string])
print(does_contain_only("a", "aaaaa")) # True
print(does_contain_only("a", "aaaba")) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

One short solution:

```py
set(string_to_check) == {'a'}

# Or, as a function:
def does_contain_only(character, target):
    return set(target) == { character }
```

You don't specify whether checking the empty string should return True or False. It is certainly the case that every character in an empty string is `'a'`. Every character is also `'b'`. These are both the case because there are no characters in the empty string, so "every character is X" is trivially true for any predicate X (even if X cannot be True for any character).

Sometimes that's what you want and sometimes it isn't. My solution above returns False for the empty string, while the possibly more obvious `all(ch == character for ch in target)` would return True.